# JPA Query selecting only specific columns without using Criteria Query?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1, criteriaquery

Is it possible to select, say, only properties **A and B from an object using a `JPA` query** without using criteria queries?

To select all properties I'd just do something like:

```
SELECT i FROM ObjectName i WHERE i.id = 10
```

But I have an object with **many** properties on a legacy system, and want to select just a few even though I'm aware selecting several properties is usually quick.

Is this possible without using criteria queries?

Comment: errm, you can do anything with string-based JPQL as you can with criteria. No idea why anyone would think otherwise.

Comment: Projections in spring-data can be used to achieve the same.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Yes, like in plain sql you could specify what kind of properties you want to select:

```
SELECT i.firstProperty, i.secondProperty FROM ObjectName i WHERE i.id=10
```

Executing this query will return a list of Object[], where each array contains the selected properties of one object.

Another way is to wrap the selected properties in a custom object and execute it in a TypedQuery:

```
String query = "SELECT NEW CustomObject(i.firstProperty, i.secondProperty) FROM ObjectName i WHERE i.id=10";
TypedQuery<CustomObject> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query , CustomObject.class);
List<CustomObject> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Examples can be found in [this](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select) article.

UPDATE 29.03.2018:

@Krish:

> @PatrickLeitermann for me its giving "Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class ***" exception . how to solve this ?

I guess you’re using JPA in the context of a Spring application, don't you? Some other people had exactly [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580851/unable-to-locate-class-after-new-object-in-select-query) and their solution was adding the fully qualified name (e. g. com.example.CustomObject) after the **SELECT NEW** keywords.

Maybe the internal implementation of the Spring data framework only recognizes classes annotated with *@Entity* or registered in a specific orm file by their simple name, which causes using this workaround.

Comment: So i need n kind of pojo for the same table? one for every need? i can't use just one object for all, leaving some fields null?

Comment: what is alternative to TypedQuery ? I need to work on jpa 1.0. There is no typed query over there.

Comment: @AndreaScarafoni, you can have multiples constructors on the same class and use it for each case.

Comment: @PatrickLeitermann for me its giving "Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class ***" exception . how to solve this ?

Comment: No, at the time I wasn't using Spring.

Comment: Can we use the same approach to fetch columns from 2 tables by using join?

Answer (score 26):

You can use something like this:

```
List<Object[]> list = em.createQuery("SELECT p.field1, p.field2 FROM Entity p").getResultList();
```

then you can iterate over it:

```
for (Object[] obj : list){
    System.out.println(obj[0]);
    System.out.println(obj[1]);
}
```

**BUT** if you have only one field in query, you get a list of the type not from Object[]

Answer (score 15):

[`Projections`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) can be used to select only specific properties(columns) of an entity object.

From the docs

> Spring Data Repositories usually return the domain model when using query methods. However, sometimes, you may need to alter the view of that model for various reasons. In [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) section, you will learn how to define projections to serve up simplified and reduced views of resources.

Define an interface with only the `getters` you want.

```
interface CustomObject {  
    String getA(); // Actual property name is A
    String getB(); // Actual property name is B 
}
```

Now return `CustomObject` from your repository like so :

```
public interface YOU_REPOSITORY_NAME extends JpaRepository<YOUR_ENTITY, Long> {
    CustomObject findByObjectName(String name);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to the same in micronaut but it shows `ERROR i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: Error instantiating type [com.example.transactions.T
ransaction$DateOfTransactionAndDateAndAmount] from introspection: No default constructor exists`

Comment: @ajinzrathod Its better to post a seperate question for that.

Answer (score 8):

Excellent answer! I do have a small addition. Regarding this solution:

```
TypedQuery<CustomObject> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query , String query = "SELECT NEW CustomObject(i.firstProperty, i.secondProperty) FROM ObjectName i WHERE i.id=100";
TypedQuery<CustomObject> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query , CustomObject.class);
List<CustomObject> results = typedQuery.getResultList();CustomObject.class);
```

To prevent a class not found error simply insert the full package name. Assuming org.company.directory is the package name of CustomObject:

```
String query = "SELECT NEW org.company.directory.CustomObject(i.firstProperty, i.secondProperty) FROM ObjectName i WHERE i.id=10";
TypedQuery<CustomObject> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query , CustomObject.class);
List<CustomObject> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could look at this link if I understood your question correctly http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/ultimate-jpa-queries-and-tips-list-part_09.html

For example they created a query like:

```
 select id, name, age, a.id as ADDRESS_ID, houseNumber, streetName ' +
 20' from person p join address a on a.id = p.address_id where p.id = 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. All you have to do is change your query to something like `SELECT i.foo, i.bar FROM ObjectName i WHERE i.id = 10`. The result of the query will be a `List` of array of `Object`. The first element in each array is the value of `i.foo` and the second element is the value `i.bar`. See the relevant section of [JPQL reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_select_clause).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I had a `users` table with an `id` column (the primary key) and a `name` column. I wanted to get the `name` field of all records, so I tried both `findName` and `findNames` but both did not work.

My solution was to create an interface with only a `getName()` method in the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    ...

    public interface UserName {
        public String getName();
    }
}
```

Then use "id not null" as the filter in my JPA repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    ...
    User.UserName findNameByIdNotNull();
}
```