# Unable to locate class after new object in select query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

When I try this query

```
public interface AppelOffreRespository    extends JpaRepository<AppelOffre, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<AppelOffre> {

     @Query("select new AOCalendarModel( ao.xx, ao.yy, ao.zz) from AO ao ...
     Set<AOCalendarModel> findAoForCalForFav(..)

...
}
```

I got this error

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class [AOCalendarModel] [select new AOCalendarMode ....
```

My model

```
public class AOCalendarModel {


    public Integer xx;
    public String yy;
    public Date zz;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where is the @Query comming from, Spring Data?

Comment: yes from spring data

Comment: Can you post the configuration part? JavaConfig or Xml? A persitance.xml you don't have, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We find the solution We just add the full path of `AOCalendarModel` which is `formbean.AOCalendarModel`

```
 @Query("select new formbean.AOCalendarModel( ao.xx, ao.yy, ao.zz) from AO ao ...
 Set<AOCalendarModel> findAoForCalForFav(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you setup Repository Scanning and annotate your entities with `@Entity`

Maybe check how you registered the `AOCalendarModel` in your Spring Container.