# SPRING data REST :How to select specific field from the repository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, repository, spring-data-jpa

In the following query I want to select only `shopname` from the order but when I execute the query it gives me an error of `PersistentEntity must not be null`
I have searched this problem but I can't find any solution
How can I get only selected rows from the Order table ?

**OrderRepository**

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
@Query("Select o.shopName from Order o where o.customer.id= :customerId ")
     String selectUsersOrder(@Param("customerId") Long customerId );
}
```

**Order.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CustomerOrder")
public class Order implements Serializable,OrderGetters {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column( nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date orderDate ;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order",targetEntity=OrderItem.class)
    private List<OrderItem> orderitem;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date completionDate ;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DeliveryStatus deliveryStatus;



    private String riderInstruction;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderType orderType;

    @ManyToOne
    private User customer;


    @OneToOne
    private User rider;

    @OneToOne
    private Address dropOffAddress;

    @OneToOne
    private Address pickupAddress;

    private String receiverName;

    private String promoCode;

    private String shopName;

    private float shoppingPrice;

    private float orderPrice;

    private float cashCollected;

    ..... Getter and setters
    }
```

Comment: You can use JPA projections. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189023/3094731) answer.

Comment: If the answer helped you don't forget to accept/upvote it...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the nativeQuery property of Spring by setting the nativeQuery value to 'true':

```
@Query("SELECT ShopName FROM CustomerOrder WHERE CustomerId = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
String selectUsersOrder(Long customerId);
```

or you can cast it to an Object[] first while fetching, than take the value you want from this object.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections) and delete your custom method from the Repo.

```
@Projection(name = "onlyShopName", types = {Order.class})
public interface OnlyShopName { 

    String getShopName();
}
```

Then GET your orders like this:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/orders?projection=onlyShopName
```