# Spring Data REST: Custom Response

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, spring-data-rest

I have the following problem. I am currently working with spring, spring-data-jpa and spring-data-rest. I want to create an rest endpoint for my jpa repository.

So, my current response of my spring-data-rest endpoint is as follows:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "game": [
      
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/game"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/game"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 0,
    "totalPages": 0,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

My problem is, that I only want to return the game part in the _embedded part. No _links, no other things. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Does [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44515534/spring-data-rest-how-to-select-specific-field-from-the-repository) answer your question?

You can use projection, Spring Data REST [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections):

> But what if you do not want address details at all? Again, by default,
> Spring Data REST exports all of its attributes (except the id). You
> can offer the consumer of your REST service an alternative by defining
> one or more projections.