# Why rest returning array of array on applying selection change in hibernate query language?

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, hql

I am working on spring mvc hibernate project using jackson. At the time of fetching data from database using rest service , If I am obtaining whole object using hql:

```
 Query q = getSession().createQuery("select r from Role order by r.id");
 return (List<Role>) q.list();
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,           
        "name": "Role1",
        "description": "XXX",
        "privilege": "YYY"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,           
        "name": "Role2",
        "description": "XXX",
        "privilege": "YYY"
    }
]
```

I get array of objects, but if I select partial objects using following hql:

```
    Query q = getSession().createQuery("select r.id , r.name from Role order by r.id");
    return (List<Role>) q.list();
```

it returns array of array.
OUTPUT:

```
[
    [
        1,
        "Role1"
    ],
    [
        2,
        "Role2"
    ]
]
```

How can I change my code so as to change this array of array as array of object.
DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,           
        "name": "Role1"            
    },
    {
        "id": 1,           
        "name": "Role2"
    }
]
```

My rest code is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/roles/" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<Role>> getRoles()
{       
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Role>>(roleDao.getRoles(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Use `Projections`. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24710759/3094731) answer.

Comment: In the link that you shared also it is mentioned that it converts it to object array. Also, I hope my problem can be solved while using query itself