# Load Joined Entity with specific columns

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have an Entity MemberBank, which is joined to another Entity AppUser by a column name updatedBy.

Now AppUser is a very heavy Model in our system, but for MemberBank I only need name information from that entity, how do map it to load only specific fields.

Here's the mapping ?

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "UPDATED_BY")
public AppUserModel getUpdatedByAppUserModel() {
    return updatedByAppUserModel;
}
```

Currently it loads the whole model, I only want it loaded for 2 3 fields, like name, id, address etc.

And just like updatedBy, it also have a field createdBy, so I have to cater both getters.

Regards.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710626/jpa-query-selecting-only-specific-columns-without-using-criteria-query

Comment: If you use HQL you could select only the required fields. Besides, I think marking a Model field as @Transient will also work.