# jhipster : unable to select specific columns

Tags: spring, angular, jhipster

when i select 4 column an error occur :

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.

```
@Query(value = "select name,rating,numberofviews,status from learningunit", nativeQuery = true)
List<Learningunit> findAllData();
```

then i add id to the query and the same error occur with different column and so on

```
@Query(value = "select id,name,rating,numberofviews,status from learningunit", nativeQuery = true)
List<Learningunit> findAllData();
```

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name summary
>   was not found in this ResultSet.

notes:i using jhipster and ever entity has a dto and mapper

**entity** 
[image: Sample Image 1]

**DTO**
[image: Sample Image 2]
Mapper
[image: Sample Image 3]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24710759/3737815

Comment: @JonRuddell i solved the problem using this query 

@Query(value = "select null as id , name,rating,numberofviews,null as status from learningunit", nativeQuery = true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**finally** i solved the problem using this query @Query(value = "select null as id , name,rating,numberofviews,null as status from learningunit", nativeQuery = true)

the point is to select null as **`the name of your column`**