# How to read specific variables of an entity from repository using a query?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

Assume that we have a persisted Entity object which has 10 variables, if I do for example  `repository.read(id)` or `repository.findById(id)` I will get back an Entity object with every variable which is set from the repository.

Is there any way using JPAQuery or EntityManager or any other possible way, that I can make the call on the repository and get back the Entity object BUT without a specific variable being fetched as well?

I have tried the following, but it doesnt seem to do anything, still brings the Set within the response:

```
JPAQuery<Fruit> query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
QFruit fruit = QFruit.Fruit;
Set<Apple> apple = new HashSet<Apple>();
query.select(fruit).from(fruit).where(fruit.id.eq(fruitId))
.createQuery().getParameters().remove(apple);
return query.fetchOne();
```

Comment: That depends entirely upon whether your JPA provider supports the concept of partial objects. AFAIK Hibernate can do it but it's a bit of a fiddle.

Comment: Honestly i refure to believe that with JPAQuery there is no way to say, `.exclude(variable)` or something similar to that.

Comment: What is the use case? Why would you want to do that? And DTO !=Entity

Comment: My bad @AlanHay , i meant to say Entity there. Its not about the use case, point made is, that the object i want to read from the repository, is already too heavy, and it also have a OneToMany relation with another object which unfortunately is tooo heavy and this has crumbled my performance. So I want now to exclude the second object from within the first object, so I can fetch the first object with much less time cost.

Comment: `@OneToMany` are lazily loaded by default. For simple properties, as the Hibernate docs note, optimisations are rarely worthwhile:  *Hibernate3 supports the lazy fetching of individual properties. This optimization technique is also known as fetch groups. Please note that this is mostly a marketing feature, as in practice, optimizing row reads is much more important than optimization of column reads. However, only loading some properties of a class might be useful **in extreme cases**, when legacy tables have hundreds of columns and the data model can not be improved.*

Comment: did you mean something like `Typed queries`? you can do `SELECT NEW CustomEntity(e.first, e.second) FROM Entity e`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710626/jpa-query-selecting-only-specific-columns-without-using-criteria-query; just a SELECT field, field in JPQL will leave the other fields "nulled".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I was trying to read specific data from an entry of a Table, because the specific table has so many data it was harassing the performance, thus bringing the whole entity just for 1 or 2 variables was not correct. 
Eventually what helped me was Tuple.
Using JPAQuery you have the advantage that you can select specific variables to be brought back from the search. 
e.g.

```
    JPAQuery<MyObject > query = new JPAQuery<>(entityManager);
    MyObject myObject  = QMyObject.MyObject ;
    Tuple response = query.select(myObject.id, myObject.version)
    .where(myObject.id.eq("12345")).or(myObject.version.eq("12345")).fetchaAll();
```

Then you can easily retrieve the Tuple object and handle the values as an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any custom POJO to get your results in and specify what is selected.

> https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_05/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor

```
public interface AppleRepository extends CrudRepository<Apple, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT new com.mypackage.Apple(a.field1, a.field2) FROM " +
           "    Apple a ")
    List<Apple> findCustomApples();
}
```

Other way is to make any particular column to be Lazy Loaded. You can do that with annotation.

Comment: so you are referring to a custom nativeQuery if im not mistaken.

Comment: Native Query can use database specifics. I am not using database specifics. It is part of JPA-QL. The other option is to go with lazy loading and make some fields lazy and don't load them, it is up to you.