# JPA: Ignore field on Fetch, but save all while saving it. Is there any annotation attribute to do so?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Entity. In this I want to fetch all data except phoneNumber. What will be the best solution? It would be fine if I could do it with annotation.

```
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "employee_name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "gender")
private char gender;

@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
private String dob;

@Column(name = "skills")
private String[] skills;

@Column(name = "phone_number")
private String phoneNumber;

//getter setter

}
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39189023/3094731) answer

Comment: Suggestion: You must filter out fields while setting response DTO.

Comment: If you mean you want to **always** fetch `phoneNumber` lazily, use `@Basic(fetch = LAZY)` and enable Hibernate's entity enhancement

Answer (score 1):

To tell what will be the best way to do this you have to say why you want to do this and what you want to achieve. 
There are many options:

- omit the getter
- use a projection (DTO or interface)
- use inhreitance
- use inheritance with @MappedSuperclass

Answer (score 1):

Can you please use `@Transient` on your field. If it is a subclass of anyclass then  on class level please use `@Embedded`.

If not then you need to read this as this is always lazy fetch From [Hibernate, Chapter 19. Improving performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties):

> Lazy attribute fetching: an attribute or single valued association is fetched when the instance variable is accessed. **This approach requires buildtime bytecode instrumentation** and is rarely necessary.

Comment: Solution you can use is removing `gettter` method from contract.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` on phoneNumber and just don't read it or set to null to prevent any read

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@Column(insertable = true, updatable = false)` and I am not sure if we can ignore while fetching using entity. you can achieve your requirements using [JPA Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

Also,`@JsonIgnore` may be useful. it is used to tell Jackson to ignore a certain property of a Java object but